# Assign cumulative values for flag for consecutive values in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

```py
x = pd.DataFrame({
    'User': ['U1','U1','U1','U1','U1','U2','U2','U2'],
    'Provider': ['P1','P1','P2','P1','P1','P1','P1','P2'],
    'Provider_key': [100,100,101,100,100,100,100,101],
    'Duration': [20,24,25,27,21,22,28,32]
})
```

This is what I want my dataframe to look like:

```py
x = pd.DataFrame({
    'User': ['U1','U1','U1','U1','U1','U2','U2','U2'],
    'Provider': ['P1','P1','P2','P1','P1','P1','P1','P2'],
    'Provider_key': ['100','100','101','100','100','100','100','101'],
    'Duration': [20,24,25,27,21,22,28,32],
    'Flag': [1,1,0,2,2,1,1,0]
})
```

I have tried using this:

```py
x['Provider_key'].groupby([
    x['User'],
    x['Provider'],
    x['Provider_key'].diff().ne(0).cumsum()
]).transform('size').ge(2).astype(int)
```

But this returns flag=1 in case of same values. How can I add cumsum in this to get the desired output?

Comment: how is the `Flag` calculated?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need [`Series.factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.factorize.html) per groups with swap order for count from bottom only for groups with 2 or more values - so added [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) by mask:

```
s = x['Provider_key'].diff().ne(0).cumsum()
s1 = x.iloc[::-1].groupby(['Provider', s])['User'].transform(lambda x: pd.factorize(x)[0]+1)
m = x.groupby(['User','Provider', s])['Provider_key'].transform('size').ge(2)
x['new'] = np.where(m, s1, 0)
print (x)
  User Provider  Provider_key  Duration  new
0   U1       P1           100        20    1
1   U1       P1           100        24    1
2   U1       P2           101        25    0
3   U1       P1           100        27    2
4   U1       P1           100        21    2
5   U2       P1           100        22    1
6   U2       P1           100        28    1
7   U2       P2           101        32    0
```